# 400 errors for half my tiles in Map Tiles API

Tags: unity, maps, augmented-reality

I have this error below for about half of my tiles (see screenshot). What can be wrong. It used to work just fine. I haven't made any edit related to the API to my scene. From my understanding, the issue happened overnight. Why does it happen and how may I fix it?

```
[2024-03-17 19:57:20.055] [error] 
[TilesetJsonLoader.cpp:889] Received status code 400 for tile content 
https://tile.googleapis.com/v1/3dtiles/datasets/CgA/files/UlRPVEYubm9kZWRhdGEucGxhbmV0b2lkPWVhcnRoLG5vZGVfZGF0YV9lcG9jaD04ODAscGF0aD0yMTYwNDE1MjUyNTE0MjcxNDQyLGNhY2hlX3ZlcnNpb249NixhbGlnbm1lbnRfdmVyc2lvbj1ST0NLVFJFRV85NjlfR09PR0xFX0RBVFVNXzIwMjMxMjA1VDA3NTNaX2dlbmVyYXRlZF9hdF8yMDI0MDIyMVQxMzA5Wg.glb?session=CLrnutPxmpqeahDDvdyvBg&key=xxx
```

I am using Unity version control, maybe something went wrong there?

[image: unity screenshot]

Comment: HTTP status code 400 means "bad request" so there could be something ill-formed about the way you're requesting tiles. It could be that you're using an outdated access key, or that Google updated the API and the code that used to work is no longer supported. Or it might just be that you exceeded a rate limit and the server is refusing to serve more tiles for a period. It will be hard for us to troubleshoot with only this: can you create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example?

Answer (score 2):

400 is the [Bad Request status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#status.400) due to something that is perceived to be a client error - in other words, it's not proceeding due to something it believes is an error from your end.

If you go to the URL in your error message (as linked [here](https://tile.googleapis.com/v1/3dtiles/datasets/CgA/files/UlRPVEYubm9kZWRhdGEucGxhbmV0b2lkPWVhcnRoLG5vZGVfZGF0YV9lcG9jaD04ODAscGF0aD0yMTYwNDE1MjUyNTE0MjcxNDQyLGNhY2hlX3ZlcnNpb249NixhbGlnbm1lbnRfdmVyc2lvbj1ST0NLVFJFRV85NjlfR09PR0xFX0RBVFVNXzIwMjMxMjA1VDA3NTNaX2dlbmVyYXRlZF9hdF8yMDI0MDIyMVQxMzA5Wg.glb?session=CLrnutPxmpqeahDDvdyvBg&key=xxx)), it states:

```
[{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "tile.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

This part: `"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."`, seems self explanatory - it doesn't like your API key. It may be that your key expired or that an error was introduced in your source somehow. Regardless of how it got that way, it appears like your API key is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if your internet connection is bad or interrupted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/111255)